# Rspec not working, or raise not raising?

Tags: ruby, tdd, rspec

I'm working on learning TDD while writing some small ruby programs.  I have the following class:

```
class MyDirectory
  def check(dir_name)
    unless File.directory?(dir_name) then
      raise RuntimeError, "#{dir_name} is not a directory"
    end
  end
end
```

and I'm trying to test it with this rspec test.

```
describe MyDirectory do
  it "should error if doesn't exist" do
    one = MyDirectory.new
    one.check("donee").should raise_exception(RuntimeError, "donee is not a directory")
  end
end
```

It never works, and I don't understand what is wrong from the rspec output.

```
Failures:

  1) MyDirectory should error if doesn't exist
     Failure/Error: one.check("donee").should raise_error(RuntimeError, "donee is not a directory")
     RuntimeError:
       donee is not a directory
     # ./lib/directory.rb:4:in `check'
     # ./spec/directory_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I'm hoping this is something simple that I'm missing, but I'm just not seeing it.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you are checking for an exception, you have to separate that from your test with lambda or the exception will bubble up.

```
 lambda {one.check("donee")}.should raise_error(RuntimeError, "donee is not a directory")
```

Edit: Since people still use this answer, here is what to do in Rspec 3:

```
 expect{one.check("donee")}.to raise_error(RuntimeError, "donee is not a directory")
```

The lambda is no longer necessary because the expect syntax takes an optional block.

Comment: I used `expect(...).to` instead of `expect{...}.to` and this answer finally helped me find the mistake!

Comment: Keep in mind that if you use the parenthesis rather than using a block the exception can bubble up.  See https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers Block syntax should be used for expecting exceptions.

Comment: what a pain.  great answer!  I never would have thought of this

Answer (score 1):

should is deprecated now so instead of this

```rb
-> { described_class.new('InValidParam') }
         .should raise_error(RuntimeError)
# or
lambda { described_class.new('InValidParam') }
         .should raise_error(RuntimeError)
```

use this:

```rb
expect { described_class.new('InValidParam') }.to raise_error(RuntimeError)
```

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher